# ASPNET authenticate fail with IIS

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis, authentication

I have develop MVC Web Application
I use ASP.Net authenticate to implement my login form
The problem is that i cannot deploy it to server.
In the first i use ASPNetDB.mdf which is a file store in AppData forlder
After that I change to store ASPNETDB as a database in SQlServer and also update the connectionstring to new database
In the development environment both of them work well
But when I deploy to IIS, I cannot login, it show me following error :
"Failed to generate a user instance of SQL Server due to failure in retrieving the user's local application data path. Please make sure the user has a local user profile on the computer. The connection will be closed."
Here is my connection string:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="ApplicationServices"
 connectionString="Data Source=.\PHDatabase; Initial Catalog=aspnetdb;User ID=sa;Password=****" />
  </connectionStrings>
```

I try to google a lot but until now, there is no result
Please help me to solve the problem
Regard

Comment: this might work? http://serverfault.com/questions/1886/failed-to-generate-a-user-instance-of-sql-server

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing machine name instead of a "."

```
Data Source=machinename\PHDatabase; Initial Catalog=aspnetdb;User ID=sa;Password=****
```

The other possibility is if you are using certain wizards like Linq2Sql etc., they might keep the connection string inside the code. Check for them as well..

Answer (score 0):

In development environment, when you are using Attached Database file from App_Data folder with SQL Express, you should use the following connectionstring

```
<add name="YourConnectionStringName" 
     connectionString="data source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Integrated Security=SSPI;
     AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|\YourDatabase.mdf;User Instance=true"  
     providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

But, when you testing or deploying with Database on the SQL Server, you should make use of following type of connectionstring

```
<add name="YourConnectionStringName" 
     connectionString="Data Source=db.YourhostedResourceName.com;
     Initial Catalog=YourDbName;User ID=yourusername;Password='yourpassword';" 
      providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```